# A function in $W^{2,p}$ for $p>n/2$ is a.e. second differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u\in W^{2,p}(B)$, with $p>\dfrac{n}{2}$. How can we see that $u$ is second differentiable almost everywhere in $B$?

This result is claimed in [Page 25](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Emooneycr/EllipticPDE_BasicTheory.pdf) but I cannot prove it. I can understand the proof of: $v\in W^{1,p}(B)$, with $p>n$ then $v$ is differentiable almost everywhere in $B$ (in the same page of the link).

My attempt so far:

I try to follow the same method as in  [Page 25](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Emooneycr/EllipticPDE_BasicTheory.pdf).

Assume that $0$ is a Lebesgue point of $D^2u\in L^p$, i.e.
$$ |B_r|^{-1}\int_{B_r}|D^2u(x)-D^2u(0)|^p\rightarrow 0, \text{as }r\rightarrow 0. \quad (*)
$$
Here $B_r$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Now, our aim is to show that $u$ is classically second diffentiable at $0$. Set
$$
h(x)= u(x)-u(0)-Du(0)x-D^2u(0)\dfrac{x^2}{2},
$$
and set $h_r(x):=h(rx)/r^{2}$. It is clear to see that it suffices to show
$$
||h_r||_{L^{\infty}(B)}\rightarrow 0, \text{as }r\rightarrow 0.\quad \textbf{(1)}
$$

Since $u\in W^{2,p}(B)$, with $p>\dfrac{n}{2}$, it is not hard to see that $u\in W^{1,q}(B)$, for some $q>n$. For example, assume for simplicity that $n>p>\frac{n}{2}$ then we can choose $q=np/(n-p)$.

By Morrey's inequality (since $q>n$),
$$
||h_r-h_r(0)||_{L^{\infty}(B)}\leq C ||Dh_r||_{L^q(B)}.
$$

Note that $h_r(0)=0$, and (*) is equivalent to $||D^2h_r||_{L^p(B)}\rightarrow 0$. Therefore, in order to finish the proof (i.e. to show $\textbf{(1)}$ is true), **we really hope to have the following inequality**
$$
||Dh_r||_{L^{q}(B)}\leq C ||D^{2}h_{r}||_{L^{p}(B)}.
$$
However, this cannot be seen by the Sobolev embedding theorem since the Sobolev embedding on a bounded domain should be
$$
||Dh_r-|B|^{-1}\int_{B}Dh_r||_{L^{q}(B)}\leq C ||D^{2}h_{r}||_{L^{p}(B)}.
$$

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: From
$$
\left\|Dh_r-|B|^{-1}\int_{B}Dh_r\right\|_{L^{q}(B)}\leq C \|D^{2}h_{r}\|_{L^{p}(B)}.
$$
and the triangle inequality, you have
$$
\left\|Dh_r\right\|_{L^{q}(B)}\leq C \|D^{2}h_{r}\|_{L^{p}(B)} + \hat C \, \left|\int_{B}Dh_r\right|.
$$

Comment: Indeed, I still cannot see how $||Dh_r||_{L^{q}}\rightarrow 0$. Are you talking about Holder's inequality to do more?

Comment: With which term on the right-hand side do you have problems?

Comment: Since $||D^{2}h_{r}||_{L^{p}} \rightarrow 0$, we need something like $ \hat C \, \left|\int_{B}Dh_r\right|< (1-\epsilon) ||Dh_{r}||_{L^{q}}$ to finish, right? But it's not clear. Note that, by applying Holder's inq, you would get $$ \hat C \, \left|\int_{B}Dh_r\right| \leq  ||Dh_{r}||_{L^{q}}.$$

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have $\int_B \nabla h_r = r^{-n} \, \int_{B_r} \nabla h = r^{-n} \, \int_{B_r} \nabla u(x) - \nabla u(0)$. If $0$ is a Lebesgue point of $\nabla u$, this goes to zero.

Comment: No, it should be $\int_B \nabla h_r = r^{-n-1} \, \int_{B_r} \nabla h $.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the $1/r^2$ scaling in $h_r$. Then, I don't know how to continue.